# How to disable Chrome media controls?

Tags: google-chrome, feature-regression

> [image]

Today when I opened Chrome and played a YouTube video the horrible thing pictured in the link appeared right next to my extensions. I've disabled it once before by disabling the Global Media Controls flag, but that solution is no longer working and the flag seems to have vanished. So, how do I disable Chrome's media controls as of August 25th, 2020?

Solutions regarding flags, scripts for violent monkey or grease monkey, or extensions would likely be best.

Comment: they removed the flag to make it PERMANENT if ceo of google could go into your house and draw it with sharpie on your screen he would

Answer (score 0):

Edit your launcher: --disable-features=GlobalMediaControls

May work for you. Works for me, Linux Chrome Version 86.0.4240.75 (Official Build) (64-bit)

I dislike the GlobalMediaControls because of the way Java is implemented in Linux.